# Mascarar retorno SQL Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-select

Estou utilizando o seguinte **SELECT** para retornar os **IDs** de uma tabela.

```
SELECT id, duracao_sessao FROM usuario
```

- Para o ID 1 quero que seja apresentado o texto "Objeto"
- Para o ID 2 quero que seja apresentado o texto "Classe"
- Para o ID 3 quero que seja apresentado o texto "Estrutura"

Existe alguma maneira de mascarar o retorno em um comando SELECT desta forma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a pergunta, apenas alguns IDs deverão ser mascarados. Se é este o objectivo, pode utilizar a expressão CASE. Por exemplo, desta forma:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN ID = 1 THEN 'Objecto'
          WHEN ID = 2 THEN 'Classe'
          WHEN ID = 3 THEN 'Estrutura'
          ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, ID)
       END
  FROM usuario
```

A instrução anterior irá devolver "Objecto", "Classe" ou "Estrutura" se o ID for, respectivamente, 1, 2 ou 3. Para os restantes IDs, irá devolver o próprio número. Se quiser aplicar a excepção para outros IDs, basta inclui-los na lista.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!!

Na verdade, todos os ID devem ser mascarados, cada um com um texto diferente entende? Teria como fazer deste jeito com 3 textos diferentes?

Comment: Não existe necessidade de usar a instrução CASE. No exemplo que mandei, o retorno é exatamente a palavra texto 1 para usuario de id 1, texto 10, para usuario de id 10... texto 100 para usuario de id 100... e por aí vai.

Comment: Ta confuso... que texto você quer para cada usuário ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, realmente estava confuso, me desculpem...Agora a pergunta apresenta exatamente os textos que preciso para cada caso e são apenas estes 3 tipos de id que tem na tabela

Comment: @dev-john, veja a resposta actualizada.

Comment: Funcionou @bruno Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: De nada, @dev-john

Answer (score 1):

Considere que sintaxe pode variar de acordo com o SGBD. Segue alguns exemplos:

```
SELECT 'Texto' + cast(id as varchar(250)) FROM tabela (MS SQL SERVER)
SELECT 'Texto' || id FROM tabela (FIREBIRD)
SELECT CONCAT('Texto', id) AS campo from tabela (MYSQL)
```

Comment: Consegui fazer da seguinte forma:

SELECT 'Texto', duracao_sessao
  FROM dbo.usuario
  Where id = 1
  select 'Texto 2', duracao_sessao
  from dbo.usuario
  where id = 2 
  select 'Texto 3', duracao_sessao
  from dbo.usuario
  where id = 3

Porém preciso fazer esse filtro em apenas uma query. Sabe se é possível?

Desde já agradeço!!

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entedi... Tu pode por no IN.. Desse jeito:

   `SELECT 'Texto ' + cast(id as varchar(250)), duracao_sessao FROM dbo.usuario WHERE id IN (1,2,3);`

Comment: Entendi, só que ele iria por o mesmo texto para o ID 1, 2 e 3 correto? Eu preciso de um texto diferente para cada ID